# Excel 2016 running in Windows 11 suddenly stopped listing recent files in the Startup screen

Tags: microsoft-excel

My desktop copy of Excel 2016 yesterday (March 20th) started not to show a list of recently opened files on the Startup screen. Today, the same problem showed up in Word and Powerpoint. I see there was an Excel update on March 12th. Newly used files still show up on the Jumplist [C:.....Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations] locations so they seem not to be able to be retrieved by Excel (and I see they are larger than historically). I cleared out the files added in the last 12 days but newly re-opened/saved documents still don't show up in the Startup > Recent Files list.  I tried relogging into the associated Microsoft account and also turning everything off and on again.  Anyone have more sophisticated ideas?

Comment: Have you done a full Office Repair?   Have you tried a different Windows User Profile?

Comment: Try in Excel *File > Options > Advanced*, under Display, choose "Show this number of Recent Workbooks" and set it to a larger value (or any other value than the current or zero).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you will have to clean you "old locations", from Start->Run execute;

```
shell:recent\AutomaticDestinations
shell:recent\CustomDestinations
```

Empty those two folders, and try to create some "recent" files.

Comment: Hi Danijel - thank you, that seems to have worked.  I had seen a comment somewhere about deleting filres from those folders and I had emptied out the ones from the last 2 weeks, and that was not effective, but I went ahead and tried your solution. and cleared out everything from both folders.  Right now, PPT, Word and Excel seem to be back to normal and I see the files I test-saved in the folders, and only them.  Fingers crossed!  Thanks again.

Comment: After clearing, maybe restart computer just in case, not sure if this "action" works on random or has sense to do it each time.

Comment: Yeah, did that (actually, even when I did the wimpy clean-out) just to be safe.  I am pretty sure it was fixed even before that, just FYI ....  anyway, another day has passed and things still seem to be working fine and back to normal.  Great suggestion, thanks again.

Comment: Not only Office 2016, Microsoft 365 Apps also have similar problems. Then around March 24, Microsoft fixed the problem.